# Electric field perturbation question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I've been practising some nice examples of electric field perturbations (aka the numbers always come out nice), so I created my own variation. This created some problems, and I would love some help. Let's say we have some unperturbed Hamiltonian $$H_0=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&\hbar\omega_0 \end{bmatrix}$$ and I introduce the perturbation $$H'=\begin{bmatrix} 0&E_0qx_0\cos{\omega_0t}\\E_0qx_0\cos{\omega_0t}&0 \end{bmatrix}$$ and so I define my new Hamiltonian $H=H_0+H'$. I also declare that my system starts off at $\psi=|0\rangle$ such that $$\psi(t)=A(t)|0\rangle+B(t)e^{-i\omega_0 t}|1\rangle$$ and I solved for coefficients: $A(t)=\cos\Omega t$ and $B(t)=-\sin\Omega t$ where $\Omega=E_0qx_0/2\hbar$. So far everything makes sense, but the problem starts when I try to determine the energy of $H$. I tried to solve the characteristic equation $\det(H-\lambda I)=0$ where $\lambda$ are my energies and I get: $$\lambda=\dfrac{1}{2}\hbar\omega_0\pm\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\hbar^2\omega_0^2+4E_0^2q^2x_0^2\cos^2{\omega_0t}}
$$ I'm not sure which energy to chose! Since my system starts off in the zeroth state with no energy, I would try to make $\lambda$ be zero at $t=0$ (using the Adiabatic theorem), but this is impossible! How do I know what energy is my system in!

The reason why I'm so interested is that later on I want to show that the time derivative of lambda is simply $Eqv$ (at least I think this should be the case). Surely there can't be two energies?

Comment: There's a lot of confusion in this question to explain. But at the simplest level you should be aware that your electric field is not zero at $t=0$ because you are using a cosine. If you simply swap the cos with sin(t) things should make more sense.

Comment: I considered that too, but does that mean the system I conjured is complete rubbish? Is there not another way to approach this?

Comment: At $t=0$ of your system the system does not start in the zeroth energy eigenstate. In favor your 0 energy eigenstate is no longer an eigenstate, but is rather a superposition of eigenstates. Said differently,  you are running into a problem because what you think are eigenstates at t=0 are not eigenstates.